# How to plot a `fevd` object using `ggplot2` in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am now doing extreme value analysis using `extRemes` package and I want to plot the return level for my results. I find that the default `plot` function in the package is not good, for example, I can not set line color, x label, and title. I wonder if we can do this in `ggplot2`?

```
library(extRemes)
library(xts)
library(ismev)
library(ggplot2)

data(rain)
precipitation <- rain
Daily <- seq(as.Date('1914-01-01'),as.Date('1961-12-30'),by = 1)
precipitation_xts <- xts(precipitation,Daily)
ams <- apply.yearly(precipitation_xts, FUN=max)
ams_df <- fortify(ams)
colnames(ams_df)[1] <- "Date"

mle <- fevd(x=ams, data=ams_df, location.fun=~Date, method = "MLE", type="GEV")
plot(x=mle, type="rl",rperiods=c(5,50,100))
```

Comment: Plotting mle will use function `plot.fevd.mle`. This is  a long function - it would be some effort to rewrite to make it ggplot2 friendly

Comment: Yes, the default function is `plot.fevd.mle` and it is not user-friendly.